# Calculating distance between markers

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a nested loop and i am trying to calculate the distance one marker is from the other excluding itself. I am using `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2)` to calculate distance however i am getting an error and i cannot seem to figure this out.

**Code**

```
function calculateDistance(p1, p2){
    return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2) / 1000).toFixed(6);
}

for(var p = 0 ; p &lt; global_citizens.length; p++){

    //console.log(global_citizens[p].socialSecurityNumber);
    pt1 = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[p].getPosition().lat(),marker[p].getPosition().lng());

    for(var k= 0; k &lt; global_citizens.length; k++){
        if(global_citizens[p].socialSecurityNumber != global_citizens[k].socialSecurityNumber){
            console.log('Comparing ' + global_citizens[p].socialSecurityNumber + ' and ' + global_citizens[k].socialSecurityNumber);

            pt2 = new new google.maps.LatLng(marker[k].getPosition().lat(),marker[k].getPosition().lng());

            var kmApart = calculateDistance(pt1,pt2);

            if(kmApart &lt;= 0.030480 ){
                console.log(global_citizens[p].socialSecurityNumber + 'is less then 100 feet from '+ global_citizens[k].socialSecurityNumber);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: ({ob:10.4915892, pb:-61.40605900000003}) is not a constructor    

...ew new google.maps.LatLng(marker[k].getPosition().lat(),marker[k].getPosition()....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your code :

```
pt2 = new new
```

remove a `new`